# Intuition for the Lipschitz-condition in Picard-Lindelöf

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In an exercise class I taught recently, someone came up to me after class and asked me about the intuition behind the Lipschitz-condition in Picard-Lindelöf.

I am aware of the examples which show, that one cannot weaken the Lipschitz-condition in the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem. But why is the Lipschitz-condition *really* there?

Is there some intuition from physics behind it? Or is it merely a technical tool to prove the theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure about what intuition there is, but the requirement of being Lipschitz can be weakened significantly while retaining uniqueness. One condition that suffices is *local Osgood continuity*. One version of the Osgood criterion can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55289/existence-uniqueness-of-solutions-to-quasi-lipschitz-odes. *Local* Osgood continuity just means that the function $\omega$ need not be the same on every neighborhood. The fact that the Lipschitz condition can be weakened makes it feel like the Lipschitz condition is simply a technical tool.

Comment: The Lipschitz condition is needed for the uniqueness. If you do not have it (or something else that is weaker than a Lipschitz condition but significantly stronger than continuity), it becomes possible for $y(t)$ to transition from being flat to increasing at a point $t_0$ without having $y'(t_0)>0$. See for example $y(t)=t^2$ at $t=0$: it's increasing (going forward in time only) but the derivative can't tell you that, which is why both it and $y(t)=0$ can solve the IVP $y'=\frac{1}{2} y^{1/2},y(0)=0$. If $f(t,y)$ is Lipschitz in $y$ then this can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/55310/5810) shows that one *can*

"weaken the Lipschitz-condition in the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem."

The Lipschitz condition is *really* there because it simplifies the proofs ​ -

both of the uniqueness result, and that vector fields satisfy that result's hypotheses.

In particular, for all vector fields f, if

the domain of f is convex ​ and ​ f is differentiable ​ and ​ f$\hspace{.032 in}$' is bounded ​ ​ ​ then f is Lipschitz.